# dbd-ODBC ruby gem require cannot require

Tags: ruby, rubygems, odbc, dbd

I have a script in Ruby, it's simple just for checking do the requires work. I've got a problem with one gem: dbd/ODBC. When I run the script I get error message. Version of Ruby is 2.3.
Here is the script:

```
begin

require "dbi"
require 'dbd/ODBC'

  puts 'This will run.'
rescue LoadError => e
  puts "This will not run #{e.backtrace.inspect}"

end
```

Here is the output with the error:

This will not run ["C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:55:in `require'", "C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygem
s/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'", "C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.
0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/ODBC.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'", "C:/Ruby23-x64/
lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in`require'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:
in `rescue in require'", "C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_e
xt/kernel_require.rb:40:in`require'", "D:/MyDoc/Scripts/check.rb:7:in `'"]

I have tried with require_relative and I have installed the gem.

Comment: There is no such thing as `dbd/odbc`? Where did you find documentation that you need to do that? It's a driver for the DBI library as far as I understand. You don't require it. It loads when you `connect` with DBI.

Comment: I've installed a gem named dbd-odbc so there is.

Comment: Yes the gem is named dbd-odbc, but it only installs it as a driver for DBI. You don't need to `require` it. Ruby loads it when you `DBI.connect`. See here for example: http://anthonylewis.com/2011/03/08/exploring-odbc-with-ruby-dbi/